# Joining Parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

What could be wrong with my expression below? 
I am trying to check that if the first value in my parameter list is checked or selected, ssrs should give me this otherwise give me the list of values selected. ="Value: " & IIF(Parameters!Code.Label = "Select All","All",Join(Parameters!Code.Label,","))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you choose "Select All" in a multi-value parameter, SSRS doesn't treat this as the actual parameter label, it will an array of labels from all the available values.

One way to get your requirement is to compare the number of selected parameters against the number of values in the parameter Dataset; if these match, all must have been selected:

```
="Value: "
  + IIf(CountRows("MyParameterDataset") = Parameters!Code.Count
    , "All"
    , Join(Parameters!Code.Label, ","))
```

If you are hard-coding the available values, i.e. not using a Dataset, you can hard code the count into the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by Field.Code.Value? Is that suppose to be parameter field? Could you please explain this line of your expression... (Fields!Code.Value, "MyParameterDataset").Thank you

Comment: That first count statement is just to get the number of rows in the Dataset... It could just as easily be `CountRows("MyParameterDataset")`. In fact, that's better, so I will update now.