# how to display multivalued parameter value in SSRS text box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am having a multivalued parameter 'client',i have almost 60 values in the client parameter,my requirement is display the  selected client values in the header text box but when i select 'SELECT ALL' option in the parameter i should display just 'ALL' rather than displaying all the 60 values.

I am using the below expression to display parameter values which is working fine

```
="For Client -" & Join(Parameters!Client.Value, ",")
```

now how can i display 'ALL' rather than displaying all the client values when i select 'Select ALL' option?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297297/joining-parameters-in-ssrs/23297541

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!YourParameter.Count=Count(Fields!DataSetFieldName.Value, "Name OF Your DataSet"),"ALL",Join(Parameters! YourParameter.Value,","))
```

Comment: I Have put some details on http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2014/09/display-all-when-select-all-in-multi.html